# WinRM connectivity issue?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012, powershell-remoting, winrm

I am trying to have a `Enter-PSSession` with a Company server with in the company network. I can RDC to the server, ping the server and also get the Windows Services status using `Get-Service -ComputerName DBServer`. However, WinRM session does not allow me to get into the server.

My PC:

- Windows 10
- Powershell 5.0
- IP: 128.2.60.102

Server:

- Windows Server 2012
- PowerShell 4.0
- IP: 10.1.130.1

On DBServer:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm e winrm/config/listerner
WSManFault
    Message
        ProviderFault
            WSManFault
                Message = The WS-Management service cannot process the
                          request. The resource URI does not support the
                          Enumerate operation.

Error number:  -2144108495 0x80338031
The WS-Management service cannot process the request because the WS-
Addressing Action URI in the request is not compatible with the resource.

PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.

PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = false
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 10
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 25
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 1024
        MaxShellsPerUser = 30
```

On Client(My machine):

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Test-WSMan -ComputerName "DBServer"
Test-WSMan : <f:WSManFault xmlns:f="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/
1/wsmanfault" Code="2150859046" Machine="MyMachine"><f:Message>WinRM cannot
complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that
the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for
the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default,
the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote
computers within the same local subnet. </f:Message></f:WSManFault>
At line:1 char:1
+ Test-WSMan -ComputerName "DBServer"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (DBServer:String) [Test-WSMan], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.TestWSManCommand

PS C:\windows\system32> winrm e winrm/config/listener
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 128.1.60.202, ::1

PS C:\windows\system32> winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

Firewall ports for WinRM are open for both HTTP and HTTPS.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: Check through the [about_Remote_Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-6) help file to makes sure everything is configured correctly.

Comment: What's the actual error you're seeing when you try to "get into the server" and how are you trying to do that?

Comment: PS C:\Users\Dilshada> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DBServer -Credential $crd
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server DBServer failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete
the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and
that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM
firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet.

Comment: For more
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName DBServer -Credential $crd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (DBServer:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed

Comment: Error message if I try to Enter-PSSession ^

Answer (score 0):

Note: The following is likely not the root cause of your problem, but it explains the error message you saw on the *server*, which is cryptic and deserves an explanation (a simple typo confounded me too and led me here).

---

**You have a *typo* in the resource URI** you're passing to `winrm e` on your server:

```
winrm e winrm/config/listerner  # note the extra "r"
```

should be:

```
winrm e winrm/config/listener
```

Unfortunately, **a reference to a *nonexistent resource URI* results in the following *cryptic error message*:

```
WSManFault
    Message
        ProviderFault
            WSManFault
                Message = The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The resource URI does not support the Enumerate operation.

Error number:  -2144108495 0x80338031
The WS-Management service cannot process the request because the WS-Addressing Action URI in the request is not compatible with the resource.
```